# pgfplots: inconsistent behavior when using \addplot3 with option shader=interp

Tags: pgfplots

I'd like to plot the contour lines of a bivariate Gaussian density with correlation coefficient either 0.75 or -0.75. Turns out that the rendering looks different when changing the coefficient even if the second plot is basically just a flipped version of the first. I believe it has something to do with the option `shader=interp` that I'm using. More precisely, the first plot doesn't look as smooth as the second one.

Figure 1 (rho=0.75):

```
\def\mux{2}
\def\muy{-1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        axis equal,
        colormap/bluered,
        xmin=-1,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=2,
        xlabel={$x_1$},
        ylabel={$x_2$},
        width=1.95in,
        height=1.95in]
    \addplot3[surf,domain=-1:5,domain y=-4:2,shader=interp] 
        {1/(2*pi*sqrt(1-0.75^2))*exp(-(1/(1-0.75^2))*((x-\mux)^2/2 - 0.75*(x-\mux)*(y-\muy) + (y-\muy)^2/2))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Figure 2 (rho=-0.75):

```
\def\mux{2}
\def\muy{-1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        axis equal,
        colormap/bluered,
        xmin=-1,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=2,
        xlabel={$x_1$},
        ylabel={$x_2$},
        width=1.95in,
        height=1.95in]
    \addplot3[surf,domain=-1:5,domain y=-4:2,shader=interp] 
        {1/(2*pi*sqrt(1-0.75^2))*exp(-(1/(1-0.75^2))*((x-\mux)^2/2 + 0.75*(x-\mux)*(y-\muy) + (y-\muy)^2/2))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

A corresponding minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \def\mux{2}
        \def\muy{-1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        axis equal,
        colormap/bluered,
        xmin=-1,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=2,
        xlabel={$x_1$},
        ylabel={$x_2$},
        width=2.95in,
        height=2.95in]
        \addplot3[surf,domain=-1:5,domain y=-4:2,shader=interp] 
        {1/(2*pi*sqrt(1-0.75^2))*exp(-(1/(1-0.75^2))*((x-\mux)^2/2 - 0.75*(x-\mux)*(y-\muy) + (y-\muy)^2/2))};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}%
    %
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \def\mux{2}
        \def\muy{-1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        view={0}{90},
        axis equal,
        colormap/bluered,
        xmin=-1,
        xmax=5,
        ymin=-4,
        ymax=2,
        xlabel={$x_1$},
        ylabel={$x_2$},
        width=2.95in,
        height=2.95in]
        \addplot3[surf,domain=-1:5,domain y=-4:2,shader=interp] 
        {1/(2*pi*sqrt(1-0.75^2))*exp(-(1/(1-0.75^2))*((x-\mux)^2/2 + 0.75*(x-\mux)*(y-\muy) + (y-\muy)^2/2))};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}%
\end{document}%
```

I'm using TeXStudio as my interface and compile with pdflatex.

So the only difference between the code of the two plots is -0.75 got replaced by +0.75 but the end result looks different. And I don't refer to the contour lines whose orientation differs of course due to the modified correlation coefficient. My question refers to the differences in the interpolation result (little squares in the center and the blue shaded area). By the way, the result looks the same no matther what pdf-viewer I'm using.

Any idea what the problem is and how it can be fixed?

Thanks a lot and all best,
VK88

Comment: Analytically the difference in both plot functions is really just `(x-\mux) \mapsto -(x-\mux)` or `(y-\muy)\mapsto -(y-\muy)`, which is precisely what you see.

Comment: My question does not refer to the analytical difference but the difference in the rendering of the figures. The interpolation in the first figure does not work as smooth as in the second figure. In the first you can clearly see little squares in the light blue shaded area, which do not appear in the second, or at least not that severe.

Comment: OK. Then please provide us with a *complete* minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}`, can be compiled, and tell us how you compile it (pdflatex etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added a minimal working example to the original post.